# Update pre-loaded database with existing data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, upgrade

I have an app which is online on play store. It comes with a preloaded database, which is bundled inside assets folder and when user initially launches the app, db is copied to preferred folder.

There is a table of favourites , in which user stores there bookmarked/favourite records.

I have new data and few other modifications which I have made with bundled database, and will be uploading  new APK to play store.

My concern is that, users who are currently using my app, they will get update notification and once they update, their app will use new bundled database, and they will lose their records stored in favourites.

I did some google search on it, and SQLiteHelper onUpgrade() works when we are creating database on runtime, but in  my case its pre-loaded bundled database.

How can I backup the favourites data before update and then load it back in new db file.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the newer versions, you should preserve the table data that you want to keep. To do this, you could:

1. Make a copy of the old database file into a backup.
2. Extract the newer database file to the working directory
3. Open **two** `SQLiteDatabase` objects, one for each database file.
4. Copy all data from the tables you want to preserve.
5. Delete the backup of the old file if everything was successful.

For step 4 you shouldn't even need to code specifically, it can be done for every table, for example more or less like this (warning, this code is untested):

```
static void copyTable(SQLiteDatabase source, SQLiteDatabase destination, String tableName)
{
    Cursor c = source.query(tableName, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    destination.beginTransaction();
    try
    {
        String[] columns = c.getColumnNames();
        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            insertValues.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
                insertValues.put(columns[i], c.getString(i));

            destination.insert(tableName, null, insertValues);
        }

        destination.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    finally
    {
        destination.endTransaction();
    }

    c.close();
}
```